# Шелест может быть пронзительным? А если очень постараться?

Tags: выбор-слов, синонимы

> Вот уже слышно сначала их <голубей> скромное курлыканье, потом
>   пронзительный шелест крыльев.

Дайте, пожалуйста, адекватный синоним!

---

Расширенный контекст (рабочий процесс: видим ошибки - кричим!):

> Всё начинается с того, что по небу между тремя и четырьмя часами
>   разливается удивительный, нежный, ласковый (А!!! МОЙ НЕЖНЫЙ ЛАСКОВЫЙ
>   ЗВЕРЬ!) оттенок терракоты. Мутный, как воды Тибра. Чуть позже на нём 
>   (НА РАЗЛИВШЕМСЯ ОТТЕНКЕ? О_о) выступят угольные силуэты высоких
>   итальянских сосен – пиний. И тогда из садов Ватикана начинает долетать
>   лёгкий шепот невиданных  (НЕВИДИМЫХ?) птах. И они не возносятся, не
>   перелетают с ветки на ветку. Они посвистывают, словно задают мелодию
>   дню. И вдруг – тишина. И теперь уже оглушительная. Но это ненадолго.
>   Безмолвие разбудит голубей. Вот уже слышно сначала их скромное
>   курлыканье, потом пронзительный шелест крыльев. Вот распахнулись и
>   стукнули первые деревянные ставни о стены старого дома. Вот потянуло в
>   открытое окно соблазнительным запахом с чьей-то кухни. Теперь вступили
>   и томные ноты только что сваренного кофе. Пять. Начинает просыпаться
>   улица.

Comment: Окружите, пожалуйста, предложение контекстом (хотя бы минимальным).

Comment: Щаз нарисуем...

Comment: Если у кофе есть томные ноты, то и шелест крыльев может быть пронзительным. Только с одним не могу согласиться: голуби-то воркуют, а курлыкают журавли. )

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Пронзительный шелест** –  вполне подходящее по смыслу определение, хот и немного авторское.

С одной стороны, это именно  шелест. **ШЕЛЕСТ**,  м. Лёгкое шуршание; шорох.

С другой стороны шелест особенный, Вовсе не тихий,  а с резким (металлическим) призвуком. Прилагательные ***громкий, резкий*** возможны, но они не так интересны.

**ПРОНЗИТЕЛЬНЫЙ**, 1. Сильно, резко **действующий на органы чувств** (о звуке, запахе, цвете и т.п.). П. визг, вопль. П. свист. П. голос.

**А вот текст я немного изменила бы**, учитывая прозвучавшую критику.

Всё начинается с того, что между тремя и четырьмя часами  разливается по небу удивительный, нежный оттенок терракоты. Мутный, как воды Тибра.

Чуть позже выступят угольные силуэты высоких итальянских сосен – пиний. И тогда из садов Ватикана начинает долетать лёгкий шепот невидимых птах. Но они **не возносятся к небу,** не перелетают с ветки на ветку. Они посвистывают, словно задают мелодию дню.

**И вдруг – тишина, оглушительная, но недолгая.**  **Предрассветное** безмолвие разбудит голубей, и вот уже слышно сначала их скромное курлыканье, а потом пронзительный шелест крыльев.

**А вот и распахнулись первые деревянные ставни, стукнули о стены старого дома. В открытое окно потянуло соблазнительным запахом с чьей-то кухни, к нему  добавился томный аромат только что сваренного кофе.** Пять. Начинает просыпаться улица.

Answer (score 1):

Всё начинается с того, что **между тремя и четырьмя часами по небу** [перестановка, возможна двусмысленность] разливается удивительный, нежный [*ласковый* убираем] оттенок терракоты. Мутный, как воды Тибра. Чуть позже [*на нём* убираем] **проступают** угольные силуэты высоких итальянских сосен – пиний. И тогда из садов Ватикана начинает долетать лёгкий шепот **невидимых** птах. И они не возносятся, не перелетают с ветки на ветку. Они посвистывают, словно задают мелодию дню. И вдруг – тишина. **[И]** Теперь уже оглушительная. **Но это ненадолго – безмолвие будит голубей.** Вот уже слышно сначала их скромное курлыканье, **потом – отчетливый** (резкий? звенящий? хлесткий?) шелест крыльев. **Вот первые деревянные ставни** [перестановка – распахнулись о стены] **распахнулись и стукнули** о стены старого дома. (Или: Вот распахнулись и стукнули первые деревянные ставни старого дома.)

Answer (score 1):

С учётом того, как взлетает и рассыпается по небу стая голубей, я бы рискнул заменить "пронзительный" на "охватывающий".

Comment: Ах, Мишель... Ох, Мишель... Ну что тебе сказать... "Michael_1812 — новый участник. Будьте дружелюбны к нему и не забывайте про нормы поведения..." Дружелюбно можно сказать, что ты мало помог мне, старому боевому коню, схрупавшему на почве р. яз. не одну собаченцию-волкодава...

Comment: Ax, Galina Avanesovna...   
«Дельвиг однажды вызвал на дуэль Булгарина. Булгарин отказался, сказав: „Скажите барону Дельвигу, что я на своем веку видел больше крови, нежели он чернил“».   
;)

Comment: Вы, Галина Аванесовна, перечитайте ещё раз весь приведённый Вами абзац. "Нежный, ласковый оттенок терракоты..." "Безмолвие разбудит голубей" "томные ноты только что сваренного кофе..."  Для такого повествования сойдёт и шелест охватывающий и трепет всепоглощающий :))

Comment: Майкл, я ж тут не автор, редактор кагбэ мы...